# Year and Range wise pivot table

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot-table

I have a table like status, size, datetime, total_day for the material stays in the place based on size.

I want to get a report like this

```
                        20          40
```

Year    Category        AF  CM  BF  AF  CM  BF
2019    22 to Above     3           2       1
        Days 1 to 5     1   1   2   1   1
        Days 15 to 21
        Days 6 to 7
        Days 8 to 14

I have used the below script to extract data from my table

```
SELECT D.STATUS, D.SIZE, TO_CHAR(D.DATETIME, 'YYYY') AS YEAR,TOTAL_DAY,
CASE WHEN TOTAL_DAY BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN 'Days 1 to 5'
   ELSE '22 to Above'
END AS "dwCategory",
CASE 
WHEN D.SIZE BETWEEN '20' AND '25' THEN '20'
ELSE '40' 
END AS "SIZE_RANGE"
FROM  TOTAL_TIME D WHERE D.DATETIME BETWEEN '01-JUN-2019' AND '30-JUN-2019';
```

STATUS  SIZE    YEAR    TOTAL DAY   dwCategory  SIZE_RANGE
AF      22      2019    8           22 to Above     20
CM  22          2019    5           Days 1 to 5     20
BF  45          2019    6           22 to Above     40
AF  45          2019    6           22 to Above     40
AF  45          2019    5           Days 1 to 5     40
AF  45          2019    11          22 to Above     40
AF  22          2019    8           22 to Above     20
AF      22      2019    6           22 to Above     20
CM      45      2019    1           Days 1 to 5     40
AF      45      2019    2           Days 1 to 5     40
BF      22      2019    1           Days 1 to 5     20

Anyone can help me to tune the script to make the pivot table as I'm very new Oracle SQL

Comment: please replace the pictures with text data. Somebody cannot see because of some filters, and using text data is easier within a fiddle.

Comment: I have tried but unable to achieve

Comment: You want to pivot on two columns so categorize data as you did and use: `pivot (sum(total_day) for (size_range, status) in  ((20, 'AF'), (40, 'AF'), (20, 'BF'), (40, 'BF'), (20, 'CM'), (40, 'CM')))`. Here is an [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=72d361c5a911872bb3cc724f410adc83).